# Cancelled BitLocker setup before setting a key: Windows says filesystem is unencrypted, Linux won't mount it

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker

I'm trying to help troubleshoot a Windows system for which BitLocker setup was started, but -- upon discovering that TPM-backed key storage wasn't available without switching to UEFI mode -- cancelled.

Windows claims that the filesystem is plain NTFS. Running `Get-BitLockerVolume` in PowerShell claims that no BitLocker volumes exist.

However, if I boot into Linux and run `lsblk`, it shows the drive as a `BitLocker` volume, and it can't be mounted as NTFS (to allow use of Linux-based partition-table conversion/resize/repair tools so we can convert to GPT, generate an EFI partition, reinstall the Windows bootloader, and thereby convert to UEFI mode in-place).

What's the cause of this disconnect?

Comment: So is the drive accessible or inaccessible within Windows?

Comment: It is accessible in Windows.

Comment: I assume you don’t want to go through the BitLocker encryption process?

Comment: I *could*, I suppose, but that would mean several hours of waiting for the process to finish to get it into a consistent state (after which I could expect Linux-based BitLocker decryption tools to work, assuming the key is saved to a file or such). And even then, I don't expect those tools to support resizing, which is part of the end game here.

Comment: Heh: Turns out Microsoft has a native `mbr2gpt` tool now, so I don't need to be able to do the relevant work from Linux anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You might get more insight running this in (privileged) cmd:

`manage-bde C: -status`

I am not sure how Bitlocker encryption was cancelled. But personally I have experienced I always needed to run an additional -off command, before I could move forward:

Run `manage-bde C: -off` which in my case cleaned up some stuff (and allow me to try again. )

Possibly this might help you too, even though I read you found another route.

---

So I have experienced drives in most bitlocker related states I can think of:

- Locked
- Unlocked
- {Unknown name - Started to encrypt -on but something went wrong, no data
  loss, but cannot -on again, need -off.}
- (Never experienced, but there is a you-must-enter-recovery-key
  state.)
- Encryption in progress
- Decryption in progress
- Protection off (# reboots left)

My guess is your drive is in the third state, hence linux seeing it as a bitlocker drive.

---

Sidenote: Ref to UEFI requirement:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/information-protection/bitlocker/bitlocker-overview-and-requirements-faq#which-trusted-platform-modules-tpms-does-bitlocker-support